# Merging audio and images to create a video using php

Tags: php

I want to merge audio and images to create a video using PHP. When I googled it, it show only ffmpeg terminal commands only. So please assist for the issue I have.

Comment: So use ffmpeg from php using exec?

Comment: I know to use exec in php but, I think when there will be many request at a time to the server, it might create problem to the server.

Comment: ffmpeg is coded to be very fast. PHP is not.

Comment: What if ffmpeg is not installed, as shared server does not have ffmpeg default?

Comment: Install it as part of deployment

Comment: But when we ask the web-server executive to install, they deny for the shared server.

Comment: If you cannot get ffmpeg installed, you cannot meet the criteria.