# PHP Convert image+audio = video

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

Hi I saw [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216520/merging-audio-and-images-to-create-a-video-using-php) Question.There is no proper rather vague answer.

He said `ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i %03d.jpg test1800.mp4` .Pretty vague.

What i want is I have 2 inputs i wil give from php file . Image,Audio ,And Output will be Video .
I saw people saying `ffmpeg` And all that .But does it/can it convert Image+Audio to Video ?? 
If yes then what should be done ?? I saw lots of questions .but **NONE** of then answers properly.I didnt see ANY PHP code to do so online.Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Converting images to video using ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864706/php-converting-images-to-video-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: @astro Its about audio also , its not duplic

Answer (score 3):

From https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

the ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest out.mp4
```

Will produce a video with a duration matching audio.wav using img.jpg as a still for the video stream.

You can use the exec() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run an external program from php code.